# Why does creating a list from a generator object take so long?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, generator, timeit

I was interested in when I should use a generator in a function, and when I should just use a list, so I did some tests with filter and list comprehensions.

```
>>> timeit.timeit('list(filter(lambda x: x%10, range(10)))')
3.281250655069016
>>> timeit.timeit('[i for i in range(10) if i%10 != 0]')
2.6070076799951494
>>> timeit.timeit('filter(lambda x: x%10, range(10))')
0.7457015149993822
```

Then I tried with range(100):

```
>>> timeit.timeit('list(filter(lambda x: x%10, range(100)))')
27.73180518404115
>>> timeit.timeit('[i for i in range(100) if i%10 != 0]')
18.659852175973356
>>> timeit.timeit('filter(lambda x: x%10, range(100))')
0.7294546449556947
```

Why does it take so much longer to make a list from the generator object than it does to simply create the list? If I needed to access that list more than once, would I just be better off using list comprehension rather than creating a list from the generator object?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham well, aren't all of them getting `next` being called multiple times? But yes, the more you call it, the longer it takes to complete iterating through the sequence.

Comment: @Dandré, `[i for i in range(10) if i%10 != 0]`, where is the next call in relation to the list itself?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham range() is a generator that has an implicit call `next`

Comment: On a sidenote, in `[i for i in range(100) if i%10 != 0]` the  `!= 0` is redundant. `if i%10` is quite enough and faster.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham he's definitely running Py3, because the list comprehension is significantly faster than the `filter` + `lambda` combo in Py2.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the `list(...)` does in implicit loop through `range()`

Comment: You have zero generators in this code. The lazy iterator returned by `filter` is not a generator.

Comment: @user2357112 What do you mean? `filter` object is a generator, is it not?

Comment: @Tanmay: It is not a generator. Generators are a very specific type of iterator based on suspending and resuming execution of a Python function, created by either a generator expression or the use of `yield`. The term does not refer to arbitrary lazy iterables.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different issues that is evident from question

1. From the minuscule timing data for the standalone filter call it is evident that you are using Python 3.x, as filter returns a generator like object. So theoretically nothing actually happens.[[1]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)
2. The first expression invokes a lambda, a function call which is always costly in Python. So, a List comprehension excels over a filter calling a lambda wrapped with a list build-in.[[2]](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Re-map_Functions_at_runtime)

Answer (score -1):

I will begin by answering your last question, yes you should use comprehensive list rather than `list` + `filter` combination since it's more pythonic and as you showed it, more efficient.

As for why it is more efficient, you have function call overhead (of the `lambda`) in the `filter` code that you don't have in the comprehension list.

Here is another timeit test to show you:

```
# First the sample with list & filter, for comparison base
>>> timeit.timeit('list(filter(lambda x: x%10, range(10)))')
10.984653161001916
# Then the quickest comprehension list
>>> timeit.timeit('[i for i in range(10) if i%10]')
6.125996000002488
# And an hybrid, comprehension list using a call to previously defined lambda
>>> timeit.timeit('[i for i in range(10) if l(i)]', setup="l=lambda x: x%10")
9.257114547002857
```

As you can see, most of the difference comes from function call overhead.

The last 1.7 unexplained seconds is probably due to the `filter` poping into `list` while comprehension list builds the values directly into the list